# How to add tooltips to JTable's rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip

how can I add tooltips to JTable's rows (Java Swing)?
These tooltips should contain same values of the relative row.

This is the code I used in my class that extends JTable. It overrides the method "prepareRenderer", but I got empty cells, and it adds a tooltip for each single cell within row, not one tooltip for the whole row (that is what I'm looking for):

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,int row, int col) {
    Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    JComponent jcomp = (JComponent)comp;
    if (comp == jcomp) {
        jcomp.setToolTipText((String)getValueAt(row, col));
    }
    return comp;
}
```

Comment: Do you need the comparison between comp and jcomp? I think it will either always work or never work...

Comment: "same values of the relative row" What does that mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> it adds a tooltip for each single cell within row, not one tooltip for the whole row

You are changing the tooltip depending on the row and column. If you only want the tooltip to change by row, then I would only check the row value and forget about the column value.

Another way to set the tooltip is to override the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method of JTable. Then you can use the `rowAtPoint(...)` method of the table to get the row and then return the appropriate tool tip for the row.

Comment: Thank you it is almost perfect! The only missing thing is that the tooltip now lasts few seconds. I would like keep it displayed until the mouse pointer is moved away. Is that possible?

Comment: This is controlled by the `ToolTipManager`. You can change the dismiss value.

Answer (score 9):

Just use below code while creation of JTable object.

```
JTable auditTable = new JTable(){

            //Implement table cell tool tips.           
            public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
                String tip = null;
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
                int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);

                try {
                    //comment row, exclude heading
                    if(rowIndex != 0){
                      tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).toString();
                    }
                } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
                    //catch null pointer exception if mouse is over an empty line
                }

                return tip;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

see `JComponent.setToolTipText()` -- the JComponent you want on per-row data is *not* the table, but rather the cell renderer of the data, which has access to configuring a JComponent for each rendered cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question with more info.

Answer (score 1):

rowIndex can be ZERO.

change:

```
if(rowIndex != 0){
   tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).toString();
}
```

by:

```
if(rowIndex >= 0){
   tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex).toString();
}
```