# How to add tooltip on JTable to show cell values of a particular column on mouseover event

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tooltip, mouseover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add tooltips to JTable’s rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332159/how-to-add-tooltips-to-jtables-rows)

I want to add tooltip for the user mouseover event on a cell under a given particular column so that the value of the cell completely displayed to the user.

Comment: what did you try so far? BTW, the references to similar questions (in the trailing the sidebar of this) are there for a reason ...

Comment: In particular, see [*Specifying Tool Tips for Cells*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think overriding prepareRenderer() may be easier for a single cell

```
JTable table = new JTable() {
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
        if (c instanceof JComponent) {
           if(column == X){
            //X is your particlur column number

            JComponent jc = (JComponent) c;
            jc.setToolTipText(getValueAt(row, column).toString());
           }
        }
        return c;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the tooltip of your cell renderer

```
public class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                                  Object value,
                                  boolean isSelected,
                                  boolean hasFocus,
                                  int row,
                                  int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        setToolTipText(...);
        return this;
    }

}
```